# NetBeans keyboard shortcut to run a file that is currently being edited

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

Is there a NetBeans shortcut to run a file that is currently being edited? Or is there a way to make one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shift-f6` will do it. `ctrl-f6` will run the corresponding test for the current file if your tests follow the conventions that nb uses for tests.

Its under the run menu, and its called "run file"